# How to read a String (file) to array in java

Tags: java, file-io

Suppose there is a file named as SUN.txt

File contains : a,b,dd,ss,

I want to make dynamic array depending upon the number of attributes in file.
If ther is a char after comma then array will be of 0-4 i.e of length 5. 
In the above mentioned case there is no Char which returns 0-3 Array of length 4. I want to read the NULL after comma too.

How do i do that?

Sundhas

Comment: I don't understand the part "NULL after comma"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should think about

- Reading the file into a String
- Splitting the file by separator ','
- Using a list for adding the characters and convert the list to an array, when the list is filled

Comment: I did spilt it by , and read that all in array issue is that the array comes  up with one less index.

Comment: @Sundhas, if you're using `String.split(",")` with each line, you may find the need to pass `-1` to the limit parameter, as in `String.split(",", -1)` in order to get the element with the empty string at the end. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 3):

As Markus said, you want to do something like this..

```
//Create a buffred reader so that you can read in the file
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
            "\\SUN.txt")));
    //The StringBuffer will be used to create a string if your file has multiple lines
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line;

    while((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
    {
        sb.append(line);
    }

    //We now split the line on the "," to get a string array of the values
    String [] store = sb.toString().split(",");
```

I do not quite understand why you would want the NULL after the comma? I am assuming that you mean after the last comma you would like that to be null in your array? I do not quite see the point in that but that is not what the question is.

If that is the case you wont read in a NULL, if after the comma there was a space, you could read that in.

If you would like a NULL you would have to add it in yourself at the end so you could do something like

```
//Create a buffred reader so that you can read in the file
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
            "\\SUN.txt")));
    //Use an arraylist to store the values including nulls
    ArrayList<String> store = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
    {
        String [] splitLine = line.split(",");
        for(String x : splitLine)
        {
            store.add(line);
        }
        //This tests to see if the last character of the line is , and will add a null into the array list
        if(line.endsWith(","))
            store.add(null);
    }

    String [] storeWithNull = store.toArray();
```

Comment: The answer is fine, but could you please remove the "C:\\"? It's a gratuitous Windows-ism that is not relevant to the question. Maybe I'm only saying this because it's 4 in the morning.

Comment: Sorry, removed the C:\\ from the code, it was just a habit from testing and didnt even know i did it :P

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want want to simply open the file and store the content in a array of string then

1) open the file into a string

2) split the string using a regex "," http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

but I'm curious why you can't use a String file directly ?

Answer (score 0):

For your datatructure, use a list of arrays. Each list entry is a line of your textfile, each entry is an array that holds the comma separated values:

```
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String line = readNextLine();  // custom method, to be implemented
while (line != null) {
  data.add(line.split(","));
  line = readNextLine();
}
```

(assuming, your file contains 1..n lines of comma separated values)

---

You may want to have it like this:

```
"a,b,c,d,"  -> {"a", "b", "c", "d", null}
```

Here's a suggestion how to solve that problem:

```
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String line = readNextLine();  // custom method, to be implemented
while (line != null) {
  String[] values = new String[5];
  String[] pieces = line.split(",");
  for (int i = 0; i<pieces.length; i++)
     values[i] = pieces[i];
  data.add(values);

  line = readNextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its seems like a CSV file something like this will work assuming it has  5 lines and 5 values

```
String [][] value = new String [5][5];
File file = new File("SUN.txt");
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = null;
int row = 0;
int col = 0;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null ){ 
StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line,",");

    while (s.hasMoreTokens()){
    value[row][col] = s.nextToken();
    col++;
}
col = 0;
row++;
}
```

i havent tested this code

Answer (score 0):

Read the file, using `BufferedReader`, one line at the time.

Use `split(",", -1)` to convert to an array of `String[]` including also empty strings beyond the last comma as part of your array.

Load the `String[]` parts into a `List`.